# Impossible to integrate Paypal Checkout on my e-commerce website using Polymer and Shadow-DOM

Tags: paypal, polymer, shadow-dom

I want to integrate Paypal Checkout on my website build with Polymer.
To do so I try to use Paypal Smart Payment Buttons which is supposed to be the simplest way to integrate Paypal.
But it seems that the Paypal Checkout library is not really compliant with Polymer and Shadow-DOM.

- First I tried to integrate the buttons from the Shadow-DOM which make the buttons appears and then disappear juste a second later. I tried many configurations but I did not find out any solutions.
- Then I tried to integrate the buttons inside an `iframe` that pointing to a HTML file which render the buttons correctly. When I click on the button I am correctly redirected to the Paypal Checkout page but a blocking error occurs inside the Paypal page and I can not finalize the payment.
- I also tried to integrated the Paypal Checkout avoiding the Paypal library but I did not find any consistent documentation to do so.
- first try (in Shadow-DOM):

```html
<div id="button"></div>
...
initPayment () {
  paypal.Buttons({
    createOrder: function(data, actions) {
      console.log(data, actions);
      let order = actions.order.create({
        purchase_units: [{
          amount: {
            value: "0.01",
            currency_code: "EUR"
          },
          reference_id: "123"
        }]
      });
      return order;
    },
    onApprove: function(data, actions) {
      return actions.order.capture().then((detail) => {
        console.log(detail);
      });
    },
    onError: function(error) {
      console.log(error);
    },
    onCancel: (data, actions) => {
      console.log(data);
    },
}).render(this.shadowRoot.querySelector("#button"));
...
```

- Second try (in `iframe`):

```html
...
<body>
  <script>
    paypal.Buttons({
      createOrder: function(data, actions) {
        console.log(data, actions);
        let order = actions.order.create({
          purchase_units: [{
            amount: {
              value: "0.01",
              currency_code: "EUR"
            },
            reference_id: "123"
          }]
        });
        return order;
      },
      onApprove: function(data, actions) {
        return actions.order.capture().then((detail) => {
          console.log(detail);
        });
      },
      onError: function(error) {
        console.log(error);
      },
      onCancel: (data, actions) => {
        console.log(data);
      },
    }).render("#button");
  </script>
  ...
  <div id="button"></div>
</body>
```

Also I observed that when I test my HTML page apart which is supposed to be include with an `iframe` the checkout works fine.

Answer (score 1):

You can work around this limitation in PayPal by adding an additional step to the checkout.

On our site we show selection of "Paypal, Apple Pay, Google Pay, CC".  When the user selects Paypal we add the following elements to the body (not in shadow dom)...

```
<div style="display: flex; width:100vw; height: 100vh;opacity:.8;background:#000">
    <div id="paypal-button" style="display:flex;flex-grow:1;align-self:center;justify-content:center"></div>
</div>
```

After that call window.paypal.Button.render with

```
style: { size: 'responsive', layout: 'vertical' }
```

This will put the PayPal button, PayPal credit button and PayPal CC buttons centered on the screen.

Then in the render onCancel/onError/onAuthorize tear down the backdrop and the paypal buttons.

Comment: I'm using the PayPal checkout.js right now - but the same works in the newer Buttons function from the sdk/js.  I don't think you need the style elements in the newer sdk/js.

Comment: I had trouble with styling when using new sdk/js within a Vue.js component. Wrapping the paypal-button-container withing an element with `display:flex` solved my problem.